# Flutter Throw Errors When opening AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter, android-studio

../android/app/source/main/AndroidManifest.xml

**Unresolved class '{applicationName}'**

**Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'**

**`MainActivity` must extend android.app.Activity**

**Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme'**

**Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'**

I created new project then I checked AndroidManifest.xml file and it throw couple of error.
My flutter looks okay on flutter doctor.

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't worry about these errors, just run your app, It should work fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Many one got this error but it is just an error of IDEs.so don't worry and run your app you will not get any error.